# Flutter/Dart Firebase Auth: Crash when updating profile photoUrl

Tags: firebase, authentication, photo

Flutter/Dart App crashes when updating user profile with the following details:
1. ios App
2. Only when updating photoUrl. Ok if only updating displayName.

my code:

```
void handleSubmit() {
      final FormState form = formKey.currentState;

      if (form.validate()) {
        form.save();
        UserUpdateInfo myInfo = new UserUpdateInfo();

        if (showButton) {
              myInfo.displayName = user.displayName;
              //-->  crash myInfo.photoUrl = user.photoURL; 

              auth.updateProfile(myInfo);
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/home");
        }


      }
    }
```

Any work arounds or solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue and there is no fix for it yet :(
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16309

Answer (score 0):

This is a serious bug!

Until the bug is fixed, ..
I got around this issue by storing the photoURL in firebase cloudstore and reference it from there.